# For loop doesn't go all around a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-requests

so i have the code down below

```
import requests
import json

with open("forex_rates.json", "r") as file:
    rate = json.load(file)
    nrate = rate

Base = input("enter your base currency: ")
if Base not in rate["rates"]:
    print("That's not a valid currency...")
    Base = input("enter your base currency: ")

with open("forex_rates.json", "r") as file:
    nrate["base"] = Base
    for i in rate["rates"]:
        nrate["rates"][i] = rate["rates"].get(i) / rate["rates"].get(Base)
        
print(nrate["rates"])
```

I'm trying to make a program that converts different currencies, for example:
1 EUR --> 1.18 USD
and in order to do this I have to edit the forex rates everytime depending on the base value
when i finished up the code i ran t and it worked all fine and it converted all values until it hit the same value in the forex value file
like if i convert from USD it will change all currency values depending on USD but when it hits the USD in the file the loop breaks
i tried for so long 'till i tried moving USD to the very bottom of the file as there is nothing after it to break. and it worked but that's for USD only.
when i change the base value inside the program it breaks again

for people saying the code isn't even finished i'd say that i almost finished this part of the program the converting part which i believe the most difficult and any other code left is only the GUI and some multiplying math

and i'll list the forex data below
#sorry if it's too big

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1597402446,
  "base":"EUR",
  "date":"2020-08-14",
  "rates":{
    "AED":4.335266,
    "AFN":91.176403,
    "ALL":123.979569,
    "AMD":572.651268,
    "ANG":2.125143,
    "AOA":695.22591,
    "ARS":86.213707,
    "AUD":1.651881,
    "AWG":2.124558,
    "AZN":2.001576,
    "BAM":1.954795,
    "BBD":2.390258,
    "BDT":100.546318,
    "BGN":1.956895,
    "BHD":0.444938,
    "BIF":2283.56194,
    "BMD":1.18031,
    "BND":1.622912,
    "BOB":8.173103,
    "BRL":6.336422,
    "BSD":1.183874,
    "BTC":0.0001,
    "BTN":88.576746,
    "BWP":13.863097,
    "BYN":2.914727,
    "BYR":23134.077322,
    "BZD":2.38624,
    "CAD":1.562064,
    "CDF":2302.785095,
    "CHF":1.074967,
    "CLF":0.033942,
    "CLP":936.574514,
    "CNY":8.203627,
    "COP":4452.129574,
    "CRC":704.672423,
    "CUC":1.18031,
    "CUP":31.278217,
    "CVE":110.201987,
    "CZK":26.106129,
    "DJF":210.746982,
    "DKK":7.446693,
    "DOP":69.149105,
    "DZD":151.514114,
    "EGP":18.805169,
    "ERN":17.704664,
    "ETB":42.448715,
    "EUR":1,
    "FJD":2.523208,
    "FKP":0.90119,
    "GBP":0.900976,
    "GEL":3.647475,
    "GGP":0.90119,
    "GHS":6.811663,
    "GIP":0.90119,
    "GMD":61.163652,
    "GNF":11418.288925,
    "GTQ":9.116687,
    "GYD":247.470583,
    "HKD":9.14817,
    "HNL":29.203723,
    "HRK":7.531326,
    "HTG":132.978265,
    "HUF":346.161502,
    "IDR":17595.177253,
    "ILS":4.019203,
    "IMP":0.90119,
    "INR":88.434024,
    "IQD":1413.229387,
    "IRR":49696.95603,
    "ISK":161.076893,
    "JEP":0.90119,
    "JMD":176.632894,
    "JOD":0.836814,
    "JPY":125.951475,
    "KES":127.822789,
    "KGS":92.238283,
    "KHR":4859.521032,
    "KMF":491.421896,
    "KPW":1062.314938,
    "KRW":1401.210938,
    "KWD":0.360975,
    "KYD":0.986486,
    "KZT":496.331879,
    "LAK":10752.381531,
    "LBP":1789.879783,
    "LKR":216.488093,
    "LRD":235.294815,
    "LSL":20.549263,
    "LTL":3.485149,
    "LVL":0.713958,
    "LYD":1.626859,
    "MAD":10.913322,
    "MDL":19.82872,
    "MGA":4566.909302,
    "MKD":61.58448,
    "MMK":1610.391686,
    "MNT":3362.205621,
    "MOP":9.449856,
    "MRO":421.37087,
    "MUR":46.799002,
    "MVR":18.243058,
    "MWK":879.737053,
    "MXN":26.199071,
    "MYR":4.949633,
    "MZN":83.979304,
    "NAD":20.548996,
    "NGN":449.107914,
    "NIO":41.242296,
    "NOK":10.544902,
    "NPR":141.752962,
    "NZD":1.80663,
    "OMR":0.454403,
    "PAB":1.183663,
    "PEN":4.2222,
    "PGK":4.165565,
    "PHP":57.516411,
    "PKR":199.282277,
    "PLN":4.396536,
    "PYG":8227.988848,
    "QAR":4.297547,
    "RON":4.835722,
    "RSD":117.576625,
    "RUB":86.625365,
    "RWF":1142.595148,
    "SAR":4.426709,
    "SBD":9.756128,
    "SCR":21.044237,
    "SDG":65.300702,
    "SEK":10.291595,
    "SGD":1.620105,
    "SHP":0.90119,
    "SLL":11537.53114,
    "SOS":689.301231,
    "SRD":8.802808,
    "STD":25132.067341,
    "SVC":10.358743,
    "SYP":603.981109,
    "SZL":20.627972,
    "THB":36.753085,
    "TJS":12.208818,
    "TMT":4.131085,
    "TND":3.240537,
    "TOP":2.698542,
    "TRY":8.706498,
    "TTD":8.006077,
    "TWD":34.707966,
    "TZS":2744.220413,
    "UAH":32.433598,
    "UGX":4343.852885,
    "USD":1.18031,
    "UYU":50.261259,
    "UZS":12111.300903,
    "VEF":11.788346,
    "VND":27353.095658,
    "VUV":134.283098,
    "WST":3.09309,
    "XAF":655.754247,
    "XAG":0.044343,
    "XAU":0.000606,
    "XCD":3.189847,
    "XDR":0.840933,
    "XOF":655.720927,
    "XPF":119.624668,
    "YER":295.426891,
    "ZAR":20.617975,
    "ZMK":10624.212769,
    "ZMW":21.85909,
    "ZWL":380.05997
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related but as a side note: `Base = input("enter your base currency: "); if Base not in rate["rates"]: print("That's not a valid currency..."); Base = input("enter your base currency: ")`
That won't work. If you input a wrong currency a second time it will let the user continue. Instead you should do `while Base not in rate["rates"]:`

Comment: Let's say you have chosen "USD" for your base rate. Two questions: When the loop has processed the USD entry, what will the exchange rate for USD in the table be? 2) When you get to the next currency after USD, what will the value of rate["rates"].get(Base) be?